# uninstall cisco vpn client (anyconnect)

Tags: cisco

I am working on buntu 12.04 LTS. currently, halt on cisco vpn client for launch,

does you know

how to uninstall cisco vpn client (any connect) from commend line on ubuntu 12.04?

or disable it for automatically start?

Answer (score 66):

Run the following shell script, type in terminal

`sudo /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh`

or

`sudo bash /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/anyconnect_uninstall.sh`

Comment: yes, thank you very much! i uninstall cisco any connect vpn client.    but operating system is still halt. when i reboot laptop and then shows us:   starting workstation server: Done.  halt....................................................................

Comment: did you find any file named as `vpnagentd` inside `/etc/init.d`? remove that. If this works let me know.

Comment: Hello

I have checked my laptop. no vpnagentd file found in /etc/init.d folder.

i have only executed ./vpn_uninstall.sh command.

no more for this.......